# Alternative to the skin modifier - solid perferated pattern

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

This is a problem I've encountered several times with blender and I've never found a good way of doing it - am I missing something?

I want to design a solid mesh pattern with holes - eg chicken wire, and apply/map/wrap it to form a shape.
The result needs to be a solid mesh that can be 3D printed - so a bump mask doesn't work.

I've create this using a wireframe mesh and the skin modifier, this is ok for a simple shapes but it's time consuming and doesn't work for complex shapes.

[image]
[image]

Is there an alternative method which would be printable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *Array* and *Simple Deform* modifiers:

- Create a plane, subdivide it. Rotate it 45°.

[image]
[image]

- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to inset, delete the inner faces.

[image]
[image]

- Use the *Snap* and the *Auto-Merge* options to duplicate it.

[image]

- Only keep one segment, duplicate it with the *Array* modifier.

[image]
[image]

- Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode, 360° angle. If it's completely twisted it's probably because you haven't applied the rotation. You can modify the segment geometry until you're happy (add edge loops, thickness, etc).

[image]

Comment: Thank you that's a much better way than what I had for that situation - I'm still looking for a way to achieve that type of thing but with an arbitrary mesh. Much like [Voronoi](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:518748) but with the ability to control the structure/pattern. I suspect the only way is going to be a script but I don't know where to start.

Comment: you can add a Displacement modifier to give it a bit of random deformations if this is what you're looking for